# Sumar valores de columnas en función de un valor anterior

Tags: r

mi problema es el siguiente

Tengo un data.table `dt` con información de códigos y valores, lo que necesito es sumar todas las columnas `imp_xn` que están contiguas a un valor `89` en la columna `cod_xn`

```
set.seed(2018)
dt <- data.table(cod_x1=sample(85:95, 10),
                 imp_x2=sample(88:90, 10, replace = TRUE),
                 cod_x3=sample(85:95, 10),
                 imp_x4=sample(85:95, 10),
                 cod_x5=sample(85:95, 10),
                 imp_X6=sample(76:90,10)
)
```

Lo primero que hago es encontrar las columnas que tienen un nombre que inicia por `cod_`

```
cods <- colnames(dt)[colnames(dt) %like% "^cod_.."]
```

Luego establezco una columna para evaluar si alguno de esos `cod_xn` contienen el valor `89`

```
dt$eval <- apply(dt[,cods, with = FALSE], 1, function(r) any(r == 89))
```

Mi duda está cuando tengo que hacer la suma de las columnas `imp_xn` que están contiguas a un valor `cod_xn == 89` a lo que he llegado es a lo siguiente:

```
dt$imp <- apply(dt, MARGIN=1, FUN=function(x) {sum(x[which(x == 89)+1], na.rm = TRUE)})
```

Pero esto me genera valores erroneos en el momento de la suma, ya que también comprueba el valor `89` en las columnas `imp_xn`

```
    cod_x1 imp_x2 cod_x3 imp_x4 cod_x5 imp_X6  eval imp valor_correcto
 1:     88     89     87     86     94     82 FALSE  87 0
 2:     89     89     90     93     92     78  TRUE 179 89
 3:     85     90     86     85     90     77 FALSE   0 0
 4:     86     90     85     88     89     85  TRUE  85 85
 5:     95     90     94     92     95     83 FALSE   0 0
 6:     92     89     88     89     85     87 FALSE 173 0
 7:     91     88     93     94     91     79 FALSE   0 0
 8:     93     89     91     90     93     80 FALSE  91 0
 9:     87     90     89     95     88     88  TRUE  95 95
10:     90     90     92     91     86     89 FALSE   0 0
```

En la columna `valor_correcto` coloco el valor que necesito como resultado de la función, ahí está mi problema.

Gracias

Answer (score 0, accepted):

En tu pregunta anterior, no me había quedado claro que lo que necesitas es sumar solo la columna siguiente de cada `cod_*`, ahora es incluso más sencillo:

```
cods <- colnames(dt) %like% "^cod_.."
imps <- !cods
dt$imp <- rowSums(matrix(dt[,cods, with=FALSE]==89, nrow=nrow(dt))*dt[,imps, with=FALSE])
dt

    cod_x1 imp_x2 cod_x3 imp_x4 cod_x5 imp_X6 imp
 1:     88     89     87     86     94     82   0
 2:     89     89     90     93     92     78  89
 3:     85     90     86     85     90     77   0
 4:     86     90     85     88     89     85  85
 5:     95     90     94     92     95     83   0
 6:     92     89     88     89     85     87   0
 7:     91     88     93     94     91     79   0
 8:     93     89     91     90     93     80   0
 9:     87     90     89     95     88     88  95
10:     90     90     92     91     86     89   0
```

- En primer lugar generamos un vector de lógicos para saber cuales son las columnas `cod*` y las `imp_*`.
- Con `matrix(dt[,cods, with=FALSE]==89, nrow=nrow(dt))` generamos una matriz de `1` y `0` que nos indican las celdas dónde encontramos el `89` en `cod_*`, las que multiplicamos por los valores de las celdas posteriores `imp_*`
- Por último, simplemente sumamos por fila mediante `rowSums()`